# Como eu redireciono a página de login para o painel de controle quando estou logado?

Tags: php, session

Com esse código eu redireciono do painel de controle  para a página de login visitantes que não estejam logados.

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
header("location: login.php");
}
?>
```

Como eu poderia aplicar o mesmo processo para a página de Login porém quando eu já estiver logado?

**Página de Login**

```
<?php
$page = "Login";
include "header.php";

$user_error = '';
$pass_error = '';
$login_error = '';

if(isset($_POST["login"])){

$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

if(empty($username)){
    $user_error = 'Please insert a username';
}
if(empty($password)){
    $pass_error = 'Please insert a password';
}
else{
    $login_check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `database`.`user` WHERE `username` = '".$username."' AND `password` = '".$password."'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($login_check) == 0){
        $login_error = 'Wrong username and password combination';
    }
}
 }
 if(empty($user_error)&& empty($pass_error)&& empty($login_error)&& isset($_POST['login'])){

$login_check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `database`.`user` WHERE `username` = '".$username."' and password = '".$password."'") or die(mysql_error());

if(mysql_num_rows($login_check) == 1){

    session_start();
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    header("Location: control-painel.php");
}
 }
 else{
$user_error = empty($user_error)?'' : htmlEntities($user_error);
$pass_error = empty($pass_error)?'' : htmlEntities($pass_error);
$login_error = empty($login_error)?'' : htmlEntities($login_error);
?>
<?php
}
include "footer.php";
?>
```

Comment: Se você entrar no login ele redirecionar para alguma pagina se a Session já estiver com usuario?

Comment: No momento que vc loga é automaticamente redirecionado para o painel de controle, mas mesmo assim vc consegue acessar o Login. Como alguém pode logar se já está logado, não é? Por isso queria deixar restrito o Login durante a sessão.

Comment: E se você fizesse o caminho inverso? No caso no primeiro código você diz, se não existir sessão usuário manda pra página login, se colocar um ELSE e mandar para index.php (painel) não resolveria?

Comment: Não funciona porque se colocar um else{header (location: control-painel;)} dentro do painel de controle vai criar um loop e a página não vai carregar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No código de `login.php` coloque assim nas primeiras linhas !!!

```
<?php
   session_start();
   if (isset($_SESSION['username']))
   {                  
       header("location: admin.php"); 
   }       
?>
```

Nas outras coloque

```
<?php
   session_start();
   if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
      header("location: login.php");
   }
?>
```

Comment: Continuo acessando a página de Login, esse $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"] tem que trocar de nome?

Comment: Não ele não precisa mudar nada! Posso ver seu código na pagina de login?

Comment: @Lukaz11 eu editei, dá uma olhada !!!

Comment: Lembrando que o [isset](http://php.net/isset) não valida se a variável está vazia, somente se ela existe. O ideal seria usar um empty também.